# Get the tag name of a form input value

Tags: javascript, html

How does one get the .tagName of a value passed in an HTML form input? This is to check whether the value that has been passed is an 'iFrame'. The input is to only accept iframes

For example:

```
//HTML
<input type="text" id="iFrame">
<button id="butt">Push</button>


//JavaScript
document.getElementById("butt").onclick = function(){
var iframe = document.getElementById("iFrame").value;

console.log(iframe.tagName);
}
```

Comment: What is `tagName` - what do you expect the value to be?

Comment: The expected value is 'iframe'.

Comment: Your variable `iframe` is the `input` element with the ID `iframe` - it has no attribute tagName - where are you getting this idea from?

Comment: are u looking for getelementbytagname()

Comment: the item passed as a value would be something like: "<iframe src="http://embed.beatport.com/player/?id=5913942&type=track" width="100%" height="162" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="max-width:600px;"></iframe>"

Comment: I just want to check if the value is an iframe*

Comment: The question is very unclear. `value` returns a string. It doesn't have `tagName` property. `tagName` is a property of the `HTMLElement` objects. "I just want to check if the value is an iframe*", does this mean you are looking for a comparison? `if (iframe === 'iframe') {}`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iFrame")
```

Comment: There is only a plural version: getElementsByTagName()

Answer (score 0):

I perhaps did not ask the question in the best way, initially.

I wanted to check if the value passed in the input field was an "iframe" (the input is to only accept iFrames). Since .value returns a string and not an HTML tag, getting the tag name through basic methods would not work. I needed another way.

For anybody else who needs a quick solution, this is how I managed to do it:

```
   document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function(){
   var iframe = document.getElementById("iFrame").value;

        var check1 = iframe.match(/iframe/g);
        var check2 = iframe.match(/frameborder/g);
        var check3 = iframe.match(/http:/g);
        var check = check1.length + check2.length + check3.length;
        if (check === 4) {
        alert("good!");
        }
  }
```

Comment: If you want the content of the input to be the markup for an iFrame, why not just test for appropriate markup? e.g. `/^<iframe\s/i.test(input.value)`